# Perl adding parameters into a loop

Tags: perl

@edit #Clarity

Objective: API Testing

Functionality: Reads the API.json and parses it. User inputs a key and gets the value.

Problem: The value for the key active equals "true" or "false", script prints "1" or " ".

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';

print "Loading API.\n";

my $json = `curl -k --silent -u admin:pass https://url...`;

print "API is loaded.\n";

my $decoded_json = parse_json ($json);

my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
my ($item, $mac);
    foreach $item (@$decoded_json) {
    my $mac = $item->{address};
    if ($input eq "active") {
        @$value = $item->{active};
    if ($value eq 1){
        print ("Device with the MAC-Adress: $mac is active!\n");
    }elsif($value eq 0){
        print ("Device with the MAC-Adress: $mac is disabled!\n");
    }else{
        print ("Device with the MAC-Adress: $mac, $input is: ", $item->{$input}, "\n");
    }
};
```

Output when user asks for id:

```
Device with MAC-Adress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, id is: 6
```

Output when user asks for device status:

```
Device with the MAC-Adress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, active is: 1
or
Device with the MAC-Adress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, active is:
```

Target: True value prints active and false value prints false.

The script obviously skips the first two ifs, and jumps to the third option and I can´t figure out why... There are no errors shown terminal.

#### After many hours of rewriting, works as intended. Solution below

```
foreach $item (@$decoded_json) {
    my $mac = $item->{address};
    
    if ($input eq "active") {
        $value = $item->{active}; 
    if ($value eq 1){
        print ("Device with the MAC-Adress: $mac is active!\n");
    }elsif($value eq ""){
        print ("Device with the MAC-Adress: $mac is disabled!\n");
    }}else{
        print ("Device with the MAC-Adress: $mac, the value of $input is: ", $item->{$input}, "\n");
    }   
};
```

Comment: So what does this print?  (What does "_aint working_" mean?)   What is `$decoded_json` like -- can you show some of it (shortened as needed)? How come this doesn't die with an error for treating a string `'active=true'` as a hash reference?  How does it behave without that added string?

Comment: (clarifying things helps people help you out, and helps those who come to this page later)

Comment: In our api there are multiple arrays in even more objects. If the value is = "null" or in an array in next object, there comes: Use of uninitialized value in print at test.pl line 17. I can´t get the script to print the value, it just spits the error

Comment: Your `@$decoded_json,'active=true'` in the `foreach` means it will loop over all of the elements in the `$decoded_json` array reference, and then the string `'active=true'`. The next line will then error because you're trying to use a string as a reference.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You talk about adding a parameter, but you're obviously misusing the word. So all you said is that you need to "add `active=true`" with no indication to what you want to add it. Please fix your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say you need to figure out where in your data structure you need to add the parameter.
Here is a example using this sample json API
https://www.appsloveworld.com/free-online-sample-rest-api-url-for-testing
Where I use Data::Dumper to look at the data structure then loop thru the structure adding active = true and then dump the structure again:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';
use Data::Dumper;

print "Loading API.\n";

# here is a test API we can access for testing
my $json = `curl -k --silent http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/Tourist?page=1`;

print "API is loaded.\n";

my $decoded_json = parse_json ($json);



print "first use Data Dumper to examine data structure:\n";
print Dumper $decoded_json;



print "\n\nNext create whatever loops you need to access the data, it appears with JSON::Parse the data is in the hash 'data'\n";

foreach my $item (@ {$decoded_json->{data}} ) {
            $item->{active} = 'true' if ($item);
         foreach my $key ( keys %{$item} ) {
             print "$key => $item->{$key} \n";
         }

}


print "\n\nlast use Data Dumper to examine data structure again:\n";
print Dumper $decoded_json;
```